# Route Guard - observable

Tags: angular, observable, angular2-routing, angular2-services

```
    import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, Router } from '@angular/router';

import { Observable } from "rxjs";

import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

@Injectable()


export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {}

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
        state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean{
            this.authService.isAuthenticated()
            .then(
                (authenticated: boolean) => {
                    if (authenticated) {
                        return true;
                    }else{
                        this.router.navigate(['/']);
                        
                    }
                }
            );
            
        }

    
}
```

I keep getting the error

> A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value.
>
> 15         state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable |
> Promise | boolean{

this code is taken a from a tutorial i am working with, tired a bunch of stuff including a return false; at the end still gives the same error.
any ideas ?

thanks

Comment: Before navigate just return false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, you need to return the Promise resulting from the then(...) method and make sure that inside the then(...) you always return a boolean, like this:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
        state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean{
            return this.authService.isAuthenticated()
            .then(
                (authenticated: boolean) => {
                    if (authenticated) {
                        return true;
                    }else{
                    this.router.navigate(['/']);
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            );
            
        }
```

And instead of `this.router.navigate(...)` it would be better to return a UrlTree in your promise and use it to change the location (documentation here: https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate).